# Call Method from a Different Event. Button Click. C#

Tags: c#, methods, visual-studio-2005, call

I'm using VS2005, trying to make WinForms.
I was wondering how to call methods from a different event to another event.
Something like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);
    }
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string testMod = e.Node.Text;
    }
```

So this is what I wanted to do, after selecting a node, when I click button3, a message box would appear. Actually, this is a simplified version of what I really wanted to do (executing a file within a particular application) but I want to understand it step-by-step since I'm not entirely knowledgeable about this thing.

Let me know if I'm lacking any details.
Thanks.

Comment: The other way around, call treeView1_AfterSelect event from button3_Click. I want to show a message box that this node has been selected when I click button3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just introduce an intermediate variable, in which you can store the value of the selected node.

```
private TreeNode selectedNode = null;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(selectedNode.Text);
}

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    selectedNode = e.Node;
}
```

There's a [`TreeView.SelectedNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns the currently selected node, making the `AfterSelect` event method unnecessary in your code sample.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
}
```

Comment: Oh. You mean to say I could totally forgo the AfterSelect? I didn't think of that. I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. A point there, the latter script is shorter totally forgoing the AterSelect event. Aside from the difference in length, are there any differences between these two scripts that may affect the entire program?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. This made it easier actually than using AfterSelect.I encountered this warning: "The private field 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.selectedNode' is assigned but its value is never used." This is just fine, right? I don't have to worry about this?